# dropdown contained within div tag hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this twitter bootstrap dropdown menu that is hidden inside a parent div like this:

[image]

**Here is my css and html:**

```
<div class="profile-gallery-image-container">
    <img src="#" />
      <div class="image-options">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.profile-gallery-image-container {
    max-width: 105px;
    max-height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid rgba(140,140,140,1);
    overflow: visible;
}

    .image-options { 
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,128,64,1);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

The z-index of the twitter-bootstrap dropdown menu is set to 1000 by default i tried fiddeling with it but it does not want to break out of the parent container. I also tried overflow: visible style but without success. How should I make it visible outside the box?

Comment: here's a jsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/DhFFC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now **define** your `position:relative;` **to your** `.profile-gallery-image-container` **class**

```
.profile-gallery-image-container {
position:relative;}
```

***[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/DhFFC/4/)***

### ---------

***[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/DhFFC/8/)***

Comment: I try adding position relative as you said but the result is the same. I'm trying to recreate the problem I have now in jsfiddle.

Comment: can u crate a jsfiddle and put your code and tell me what is correct the problum